# deploying lambdas with environment variable conditions

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I already tried to deploy 1 lambda using terraform. Question is - I plan to only deploy the lambda using the current code I made, what if I need to deploy 2nd, 3rd and 4rth lambda using same code but having different environment variables? please see below for the sample scenario

```
LAMBDA-1 = hello-Earth
ENV VARS:
    KMS-KEY-1 = data.aws_kms_key.key1.id
    KMS-KEY-2 = data.aws_kms_key.key2.id
    ENV = DEV

LAMBDA-2 = hello-Mars
ENV VARS:
    KMS-KEY-1 = data.aws_kms_key.key1.id
    KMS-KEY-2 = data.aws_kms_key.key2.id
    ENV = SQA
    VARIETY = HOT
    SIZE = LARGE

LAMBDA-3 = hello-Neptune
ENV VARS:
    KMS-KEY-1 = data.aws_kms_key.key1.id
    KMS-KEY-2 = data.aws_kms_key.key2.id
    ENV = UAT
    VARIETY = COLD
    SIZE = MEDIUM
    DISTANCE = FAR

LAMBDA-4 = hello-Pluto
ENV VARS
    ENV = PROD
    SIZE = SMALL
    DISTANCE = FAR
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What Terraform code have you written so far? Can you edit it into your question? Does it error? If so include the full error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aws_lambda_function resource has an [environment argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#variables). Within that you can define your environment variables.

So your lambda function resources would be the same but with different environment arguments like shown below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello-Earth" {
  filename      = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name = "hello-Earth"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler       = "exports.test"

  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("lambda_function_payload.zip")}"

  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  environment {
    variables = {
      KMS-KEY-1 = data.aws_kms_key.key1.id
      KMS-KEY-2 = data.aws_kms_key.key2.id
      ENV = "UAT"
      VARIETY = "COLD"
      SIZE = "MEDIUM"
      DISTANCE = "FAR"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello-Mars" {
  filename      = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name = "hello-Mars"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler       = "exports.test"

  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("lambda_function_payload.zip")}"

  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  environment {
    variables = {
      KMS-KEY-1 = data.aws_kms_key.key1.id
      KMS-KEY-2 = data.aws_kms_key.key2.id
      ENV = "SQA"
      VARIETY = "HOT"
      SIZE = "LARGE"
    }
  }
}
```